# Can I suppress command window output of a function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

In Matlab I often use functions in my script that output something to the command window in one or several ways, for instance like this:

```
function output = mySubFunction(input)
    disp(['the input is: ', num2str(input)])
    output = input * 2;
    disp(['the output is: ', num2str(output)])
end
```

If I now use this function in my script it would look something like this:

```
data = 5;
disp('applying transformation...')
transformation = mySubFunction(data);
disp(['the result of the transformation is: ', num2str(transformation)])
```

This is of course a very simple example, in fact the functions are often quite complicated and give a lot of output. In this case, to keep a better overview of what is going on in my main script using my command window, I would like to suppress the disp() functions in my mySubFunction. Is there any way that I can do this simply from my main script (that is, without diving into possibly very complicated functions and subfunctions to comment out all disp() functions or insert semicolons)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want [`evalc`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/evalc.html).

From the MATLAB-documentation (the function is similar in Octave):

> Use the "evalc" function to redirect all the output displayed on the
> command window to a variable. This will not suppress figures, but it
> does allow you to prevent print statements from being displayed in the
> command window.

As an example:

```
[results, output] = evalc('mySubFunction(3)');
```

This displays nothing but stores the following variables in the workspace:

```
>> [results, output] = evalc('mySubFunction(3)');
>> ans
ans = 6
>> output
output = 6
>> results
results = the input is: 3
the output is: 6
```

Comment: I think this is solving a different problem, but useful insight nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this in any language as far as I'm concerned, not just matlab / octave, is to have a 'debug' or 'verbose' variable present, which is checked against an if statement and decides whether to print those logs. The if statement could be used in the relevant code directly, or wrapped inside a 'prettier' function responsible for doing the logging.

This variable may be passed explicitly to the function, or it could be a global variable. If you plan to run your script directly from the shell rather than directly from a matlab/octave environment, it could even be detected from from a shell-defined environmental variable. Alternatively, it could be read from a config file. It all depends on your use case.

---

For the sake of an example, here is your session, transformed as above, using the global variable approach.

```
%% in file mainScript.m 
global VERBOSE
VERBOSE = true;
data = 5;
if VERBOSE, disp('applying transformation...'); end
transformation = mySubFunction(data);
if VERBOSE, disp(['the result of the transformation is: ', num2str(transformation)]); end

%% in file mySubFunction.m 
function output = mySubFunction(input)
    global VERBOSE
    if VERBOSE, disp(['the input is: ', num2str(input)]); end
    output = input * 2;
    if VERBOSE, disp(['the output is: ', num2str(output)]); end
end
```

Comment: Agree, this is likely the simplest way to do "print debugging". On the other hand, I'd argue that in MATLAB or Octave you don't need print statements, the built-in debugger is so easy to use and so powerful.

Comment: I beat your second comment by 2 seconds Cris :)    I don't agree about 'print debugging' being unnecessary. Yes if all you're doing is debugging then using the debugger is better, but you'd have a hard time convincing me that keeping logs is not useful beyond simple runtime debugging. Point taken though. OP, if you're reading this, you are well advised to learn the debugger!

Comment: Yes, you did! Funny! -- sure, there are cases where keeping a log of what is going on is useful. And in long-running processes it can be nice to know how far along it is, I often add a `disp` statement at the top of a loop. But OP's example looks like stuff the debugger would be better at.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I agree the debugger is great and my main way of solving issues. But indeed I am running long processes and like to keep an eye on what happened. As I am using functions from toolboxes made by other people, it's very impractical to go through them and put if-statements in everywhere. However, @TasosPapastylianou mentioned the term logging, and perhaps the best solution for this problem is writing the disp messages that I want to see to a separate log file. This way I could have a quick overview of what happened over the course of multiple hours.

Comment: I like the answer, and it looks like OP does too, but does it really answer the question? _"Is there any way that I can do this simply from my main script (that is, without diving into possibly very complicated functions and subfunctions"_ This answer seems to require diving into the complicated functions and subfunctions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @round_circle thank you for the extra info. If you don't have full control of all outputs, and what you're after is to redirecting output appropriately, depending on whether you generated it or not, then yes, putting what you control in a logfile is probably the best approach. Other things you can consider are: 1. using `diary` to record the output of your whole session, and introduce handy identifiers you can search for later when you revisit the file. 2. Overwrite the 'disp' function with one that calls builtin( 'disp') appropriately under the hood (caveat: this will only affect disp calls).

Comment: @StewieGriffin I interpret "from my main script" and the question more generally to mean "Can I adapt my program[ing] so as to be able to easily toggle something on/off globally before each run, which would change the printing behaviour of my whole script, rather than having to go around uncommenting individual print lines in files before each run instead". I didn't interpret it as "I don't want to change anything anywhere because of restrictions, but I want to inspect an output at a single point in my program, can I do that?".

Comment: You might be right, and if OP is "willing" to make changes to the individual files, I would definitely do something like what you propose and not use workarounds like `evalc`. `eval` is evil after all.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks, I did not know about diary yet!

Comment: @StewieGriffin could you elaborate why eval is evil (even when you were maybe not 100% serious)?

Comment: `eval` can be quite useful if used the right way. But it's often combined with dynamic variable and function names such as `eval(['x, num2str(i), ' = myfun(', num2str(k), ')'])`. Using `eval` that way is evil, since it's bad bad bad in Matlab. The phrase "eval is evil" is from Javascript, where using eval can (or maybe could) cause some serious problems.

Comment: @round_circle 'eval' is a way of allowing a string representing code to be evaluated at _runtime_. There are two main reasons (among many) why `eval` (in any language) is considered "evil": 1. The compiler/interpreter cannot perform any optimizations, since that string could literally be _anything_! 2. It opens up all sorts of security problems, because someone could easily sneak in code into that string that does something malicious, especially if the string comes from user-input. Imagine `eval(s)` where you expect `s` to be a simple addition, and the user provides `s = "format C:"` instead.